# C# Отправка файла POST-запросом на PHP-скрипт

Tags: c#, post

Есть программа в которой время от времени создается лог файл (log.txt) который надо передать на php скрипт для сохранения.
Есть рабочий вариант на html. Нужно тоже самое только на C#.

Код html:

```
<form action="http://site.ru/in.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Код php:

```
<?php if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["pass_file"]["tmp_name"])){
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pass_file"]["tmp_name"], "files/".$_FILES["pass_file"]["name"]);
 echo "OK";} else {
  echo("ERROR");?>
```

Мои познания C# заканчиваются на этом:

Код C#

```
 WebRequest send = WebRequest.Create("http://site.ru/in.php");
 send.Method = "POST";
 send.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
```

Пробовал так:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var send = wc.UploadFile("http://site.ru/in.php", "POST", @"C:\Programm\log.txt");
```

Comment: Лог файл-ы тяжелые?

Comment: Максимум 200кб.

Comment: Отправляйте строку через POST запрос на php гейт, гейт же уже будет маркировать и записывать в лог\и данные.

Comment: Неужели нельзя просто файл отправить?

Comment: Можно, но строкой проще. Читайте: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131425/send-a-file-via-http-post-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("http://site/upload.php", @"c:\some\file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
string fileName = "C:\text.txt";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://site.ru/in.php");
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file", fileName, "text/txt");
byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
requestStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
fileStream.Close();

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    return (int)response.StatusCode;
}
```